# MVC3 Form binding duplicated across two neighbouring html forms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I have a scenario where I have a login form next to a registration form, as the login form is a permanent fixture (until much further development), and sometimes registration as the main content coincides with this login form.

Now we enter the twilight zone:  Both forms have different actions on different controllers, but they share two things in common, being they both have a `ValidationSummary`, and they both have a field called `UserName`.  If I cause a server side validation error, e.g. when the user hasn't ticked 'Accept terms of use', using

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "You must accept the Terms and Conditions to become a member.");
```

the error is displayed in the validation summaries of both forms, and the new user name, i.e. the user trying to register, is displayed in the `UserName` field on both forms.  The forms don't even share a common view model *type*, let alone instance.  All I can ask to make this properly a question is WTF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your html elements have the same Id you might expect this kind of behaviors. I think that the easiest solution for this is **to rename your login username id name into a more explicit one** like LoginUserName. this way you are not mixing two different things.

Second, I suggest you (if you haven't done so) to encapsulate your login functionality into a separate form (if that applies) because you would be sending the whole page, including use cases that don't apply to a login action.

Comment: I'm going with your renaming for now, as it's the most practical and immediate solution.  I do still have a problem with the validation summary however, as I have no access to a client id for this as I have no way to specify this in attributes.

Comment: Could you explain why you don't have access to client Id? as far as I know you can handle everything on the page using the model-binding  feature, as long as the property you want to handle is contained on your model class (which goes on your page with @model yourmodel). Am I right or maybe is other your problem?

Comment: I mean write access to the client ID.  I haven't tried @archil's suggestion regarding binding prefixes yet, but besides that, the ValidationSummary exposes very little API.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the issue with same client input names. Take a look at [BindAttribute.Prefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute.prefix.aspx) and [TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.templateinfo.htmlfieldprefix.aspx). By using them you can generate different client ids and names for those different actions and models, and the problem will probably be solved. `HtmlFieldPrefix` is used for appending prefix for client generated ids, and the `Bind.Prefix` is used for binding back client form values generated with `HtmlFieldPrefix`. Both of them are set in controller action.

Comment: I accepted Rodrigo's answer because it is already working for me, but I think yours is what I must look into in future.  I don't like 'human intervention' in naming model properties.

Comment: All you need in you case is different client ids at specific place, nothing more. You are right, renaming model properties may cause more trouble in more places than applying custom prefix in single place