# How do I implement a logon HTML form as part of my master layout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a requirement to include logon fields in my right column of a 3 column layout, with the body view being the centre.  Right now I simply have Logon actions in my home controller, but IN haven't given this much work yet and am running into difficulties.  I use a partial view for the HTML form with login fields, but I want to move the logon actions into my Account controller.  However, my quandary is how to. so to say, return a partial view from an action method, e.g. for a bad logon message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that purpose, [Html.RenderAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.renderaction.aspx) is used. Simple way to inject output of other menu, logon, etc. actions into generated html

Comment: Thanks, that was a great thing to learn this morning, but now when I click submit on my main view, e.g. BeginRegistration, I get client validation errors on my unpopulated login fields.  How do I segregate the form submits?  My form actions are correct.

Comment: Possibly cause of same names  UserName, Password, etc. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642596/mvc3-form-binding-duplicated-across-two-neighbouring-html-forms/6643121#6643121

Comment: I've already renamed the fields, but the problem is the submit on the main view is submitting for the partial as well, so I'm now getting an actual auth failure on the login post action.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use AJAX or you submit the form back?

I would suggest using AJAX to send the form data. If the login is unsuccessful you can return some string or whatever message you like (you can also return the partial view), if it is successful you can authenticate the user and redirect to home page.